# JSON UTF-8 Encode Volley Android

Tags: android, json, utf-8, android-volley

I am new to android and volley, I did a tutorial in [this](https://dedykuncoro.com/2016/03/membuat-aplikasi-android-news.html) link. But when I parse the data from my database the result is just "?????" replacing russian characters. Since I am new to programming, I couldn't add UTF-8 to my code below. I really would like to be shown where exactly to add extra code so it reads other languages not only English. Thanks in advance. Extra code can be seen from the link provided below.

```js
private void callNews(int page){

        swipe.setRefreshing(true);

        // Creating volley request obj
        JsonArrayRequest arrReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url_list + page,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

                        if (response.length() > 0) {
                            // Parsing json
                            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                                try {

                                    JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                    NewsData news = new NewsData();

                                    no = obj.getInt(TAG_NO);

                                    news.setId(obj.getString(TAG_ID));
                                    news.setJudul(obj.getString(TAG_JUDUL));

                                    if (obj.getString(TAG_GAMBAR) != "") {
                                        news.setGambar(obj.getString(TAG_GAMBAR));
                                    }

                                    news.setDatetime(obj.getString(TAG_TGL));
                                    news.setIsi(obj.getString(TAG_ISI));

                                    // adding news to news array
                                    newsList.add(news);

                                    if (no > offSet)
                                        offSet = no;

                                    Log.d(TAG, "offSet " + offSet);

                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    Log.e(TAG, "JSON Parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                                }

                                // notifying list adapter about data changes
                                // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        }
                        swipe.setRefreshing(false);
                    }

                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                swipe.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        });

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(arrReq);
    }
```

Comment: AFAIK there is no problem with tour code but with server response ... fx content-type charset is different from the one used in response body

Comment: Dear Selvin but how to fix content-type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who might be seeking the same solution. I got the solution by changing "obj.getString" into this "news.setJudul(new String (obj.getString(TAG_JUDUL).getBytes("UTF-8")));".